# RDP to Hyper-V VM Guest on Network

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V VM that I can remote into from the host no problem, however I want to be able to remote into it from another computer on the network. What needs to be configured to make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you connect to VM with Virtual Machine Console.
For connect to VM from LAN over RDP you need:

- open incoming port 3389 on target machine
- add user you try login over RDP to «Remote Desktop Users» security group on target machine

Comment: I can RDP into the Guest from the Host with no issue. I think the issue is the IP of the guest is not available on the network since when I try to connect it from another machine it times out but not sure where to look.

Comment: @IsaacLevin Can you capture screencast?

Comment: I cannot at the moment, I can take a look at a setting if you need

Comment: @IsaacLevin have you tried to connect?

Comment: What should I be looking at? The issue has to be the IP for the Guest isn't available to the network

Comment: @IsaacLevin send me VM Settings window screenshot

Comment: I was able to figure it out by following a doc on docs.microsoft.com, funny that. Thanks for the help

Comment: @IsaacLevin Can you share the link? Thanks.